# SQL exception error: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I was given a quite old project to look after. During some debugging, I realise the developer did this:

```
using (var datareader = await readerhelper.GetReader(para1, para2))
{
    var result = _mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<object>>(datareader);
}
```

In the `readerHelper`, we have code like this:

```
public static async Task<SqlDataReader> GetReader(some parameters)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand= new SqlCommand())
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connString");
        sqlCommand.Connection = conn;

        // open the query
        var sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        return sqlDataReader;
    }
}
```

As we can see, these code do not dispose the `SqlConnection`, but the connection indeed got closed when `sqlDataReader` finishes (as the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`is used).

From application insights, I saw some unhandled exception such as this:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenTdsConnection
>
> Outer Message
> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.
>
> Innermost Message
> Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

I can't link these exceptions to anything and I can't see any background timer or task. So could this error be linked to the fact that we don't dispose connection (we do close it for sure).

The developer said he did this way as it takes some resource and time to create SQL connection, as the connection is closed by the reader anyway, he doesn't think there is any problem.

Is he correct? Or the exceptions I saw indeed linked to the fact that we do not dispose `SqlException`?

Comment: I hope this didn't get submitted as completed work because there's no way this was tested beyond "it compiles". It ignores the fundamental design of how these objects work *together*. When it disposes the command object, much of what the reader object needs becomes unavailable to it. Many, many hand slaps required here. Chuck it and rewrite it properly.

Comment: You're disposing the command, but not the connection and reader, what else do you expect? Where does `conn` come from, why are you not disposing it also?

Comment: What this code needs, to become reusable (which is really what the author appears to be trying to do), is to accept a higher-order function (a delegate) that uses the reader and returns its result, which this method then returns as its result. Then it can dispose the reader, the command, and the connection, *in that order*, before returning.

Comment: @madreflection Is exactly how I often implement these things: take a `Action<SqlDataReader>`, or sometimes a `Func<SqlDataReader, T>` and then return `List<T>`

Comment: @madreflection I omitted a couple of lines like open connection etc, also the reader is disposed properly with the using bracket. With the .CloseConnection behaviour, the connection will also be closed when reader is disposed. That is why the developer believe there is no issue

Comment: @madreflection also according to microsoft doc https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling, apparently disposed connection or closed connection will all be put back into the connection pool.  The developer demonstrated that by not disposing a connection (just close it in data reader), we can actually get around 20% performance gain (seems to be true in the high frequency world this application was used). But I am wondering if the unhandled exceptions I see in the log is the price we pay for this approach, although seems not harming much.

Comment: The stated code seems like it could also be missing several classes of SqlExceptions that only get thrown once all of the data reader's results have been consumed by way of the `NextResult()` method. Have a read through Dan Guzman's blog post, [The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).

Comment: Performance is more than just speed; it includes stability. If you're sacrificing stability for speed, that's not a performance improvement. All you're doing is trading one problem for another. The fact that you're getting the exception means you're doing something wrong. You can argue around that, but changing the subject doesn't erase the mistake. It just ignores it. If you came here with your mind made up, you're going to do it anyway and there was no point in posting in the first place.

Comment: @madreflection This developer didn't do things by the common approach, but after I dig into the doc, it is hard to argue against.  As I can't find a single line of code is actually wrong, I have to accept it as correct, seems you will believe it is wrong purely because it looks very different.

Comment: @madreflection also not sure how you draw the conclusion that we are sacrificing stability for speed. The exceptions are something can be seen from appinsights or if I take an IIS dump in winddebug in the old old way, however it seems not linked to any request. If you ever take IIS dump using windebug before, you will know that .net framework throw all kind of exceptions to do things internally. Whether this is one, I don't know.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Maybe, I am not too sure